# How domain provider's DNS name server entries work?

Tags: dns, bind, nameserver

Scenario: You buy domain abc.com from provider XYZ.
You want to host your own DNS server on example.com
(on ns1.example.com ns2.example.com). The domain and both subdomains will point to same IP.

XYZ allows you to create some "magic" entries where you say
ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com are name servers and point to those IPs.

My question is if you host your own DNS server how can the domain provider (XYZ) provide those 2 "magic" entries ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple DNS Question](http://serverfault.com/questions/72020/simple-dns-question)

Answer (score 7):

What you are after are called "glue records".

> A glue record is the IP address of a name server held at the Domain
>   Name registry.
>
> Glue records are required when you wish to set the name servers of a
>   domain name to a hostname under the domain name itself.
>
> For example if you wished to set the name servers of example.com to
>   ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com you would need to also provide the
>   glue records (i.e. the IP addresses) for ns1.example.com and
>   ns2.example.com.
>
> If you did not provide the glue records for these name servers then
>   your domain name would not work as anyone requiring DNS information
>   for it would get stuck in a loop:
>
> What is the name server for example.com? -> ns1.example.com What is
>   the IP address of ns1.example.com? -> don't know, try looking at name
>   server for example.com What is the name server for example.com? ->
>   ns1.example.com
>
> ...and so on.
>
> With the glue record in place the registry will hold the IP address
>   and the loop will not occur:
>
> What is the name server for example.com? -> ns1.example.com What is
>   the IP address of ns1.example.com? -> [IP Address]

http://faq.domainmonster.com/dns/glue_record/

Comment: As "Glue records are required when you wish to set the name servers of a domain name to a hostname under the domain name itself." does it means that if you want to set the name servers as pure IPs you might not need glue records?

Comment: I don't think you can actually do this. You need a domain name / hostname, but you could of course use another domain name for it (which then allows it to be resolved without glue records)

Comment: Ok, so not possible. Then how does a domain provider resolve this issue for itself? Does a domain provider has more "powers", granted by IANA (or others), than a normal dns server?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The GLUE record is recorded in the TLD zone, not at any specific provider

Comment: As I can see glue records are used/appear in 2 places: inside provider's control panel for the domain and inside your TLD zone file.
Now, if it would be the beginning of the internet and it would be the first domain provider...how it should add those glue records...as there is no provider for the initial provider?

Comment: you will need to ask your provider on what exactly they do in the control panel. The above is how DNS works. What they do (additionally) with that record is their business