# Resolving a domain's NS when it points at the same domain

Tags: dns

Reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1215290/host-dns-server-from-home-using-static-ip) question got me thinking:

> I want to host a DNS server for my home website from my home (which has a static IP) what do I need to do?

I'm comfortable with DNS and how it works, but this question lead me down a path I've not considered before.

Suppose I host a DNS server for my own domain (`example.com`) at `1.2.3.4`, and this DNS server advertises the following (simplified) zone:

```
@   NS ns.domain.com.
@   A  1.2.3.4
ns  A  1.2.3.4
```

I then subsequently register `ns.example.com` as `example.com`'s name server with my registrar.

We can't resolve the address of `ns.example.com` without first knowing who is responsible for `example.com`.

Once we know that `ns.example.com` is the name server for `example.com` won't we get stuck? Surely there is no way to contact `ns.example.com` because the A record identifying their IP address is held by that same server...?

Presumably there is a step that I'm missing in the lookup...

---

Having read [this](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2014/07/01/dns-lookup-domain-name-ip-address/), my understanding is confirmed but I'm still left puzzled...

It looks like this is possible, as `google.com` appears to be configured this way (as outlined in the linked article).

Isn't there a step missing between 5 and 6?

> **Step 5:** [...] The .com gTLD server responds with a list of all of google.com’s NS records. In this case Google has four name servers, “ns1.google.com” to “ns4.google.com.”
>
> **Step 6:** Finally, the DNS resolver queries one of Google’s name server for the IP of “www.google.com.”

... yes, but we need to know the IP of one of these nameservers to query them, effectively swapping a `www.google.com` query out for an interim `ns1.google.com` query.

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate of _something_

Comment: @grawity - very probable, but thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/870028/how-domain-providers-dns-name-server-entries-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, the parent zone *has a copy* of the relevant A/AAAA records – called **glue records** – so in  'Step 5' the server automatically includes them in the response and no further nested queries are needed.

Any response that includes NS records (whether it was a direct query for NS records, or whether it was an ordinary query that generates a referral) will always include the corresponding glue records under the "ADDITIONAL" section:

```
$ dig google.com. A @c.gtld-servers.net.

;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 9

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
...

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:32::a
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  AAAA    2001:4860:4802:34::a
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.34.10
...
```

(This copy is managed manually – when the domain's owner configures nameservers in the parent zone, they [may also specify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9lo3.png) the IP addresses along with the names.)

As an example of how the records are actually *stored,* you can take a look at [the root zone](http://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone) which has many such delegations with glue records – they're simply placed inline in the parent zone:

```
lt.             172800  IN  NS      a.tld.lt.
lt.             172800  IN  NS      b.tld.lt.
a.tld.lt.       172800  IN  A       195.8.218.131
b.tld.lt.       172800  IN  A       194.0.20.1
b.tld.lt.       172800  IN  AAAA    2001:678:19:0:0:0:0:1
```

As a final note, glue records only become mandatory for same-domain nameservers, but they are **not required** when a loop wouldn't occur – it is very common for domain A to use nameservers from under domain B, in which case the parent zone often won't have glue records and the client will indeed have to do additional queries on its own.

Comment: Thanks! You jogged my memory (Glue records)... I did know this once, but I've never done anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

Step 5 on that article says:

> [...] The .com gTLD server does not have the IP addresses for google.com, but it knows the location of google.com’s name servers. The .com gTLD server responds with a list of all of google.com’s NS records.

If I'm not wrong, although the *.com* gTLD server does not have **records** for the IP addresses for *google.com*, knowing the location of *google.com*'s name server it can query the IP addresses and respond with them.

Perhaps doing some experimentation with `dig` using `+trace` and `+norecurse` in several steps can clarify what's going on.